# Change Focus to main Form

Tags: c#, winforms

In my program, I click a button to go to a different form, and on the form it always focuses on a (read only) textbox (highlights its content).

How do I get it to focus on the form instead?

I've tried using `.Focus()` and `ActiveControl`.

`Active Control` worked, but I got an error that said "control not found", but then when I clicked "continue", it loaded up the form just fine, and didn't highlight the textbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ActiveControl = null;` in the `Activated` event of the form.

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward solution! :)